# Android Studio: onTouchEvent either doesn't run or can't update variables

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ive been trying to program an app on android studio and the onTouchEvent doesn't seem to update my variables.

my variables are defined in the main activity NOT a method, like this:

```
public float touchy;
public float touchx;
```

my onTouchEvent code like this:

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {




    touchx = (float) 200.0;//event.getX(); ive tried to just put solid numbers
    touchy = (float) 200.0;//event.getY(); but even that doesnt seem to work

    return true;
}
```

This is put to the test in my image button "movecircle" (and yes, it runs)

```
    public void MoveCircleOnClick(View view) {

    if (touchx >0){
        YOU.setY(50);//<<<this is to see if there is a result: there isnt
    }
```

my goal is when MoveCircleOnClick is run, YOU,(imageview) will be transported to  touchx and touchy coodinates. like this

```
YOU.setY(touchy);
YOU.setX(touchx);
```

//Would bounty but I don't have enough rep.     :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you implemented 'onTouchListener' interface in the MainActivity. 
Then what you need to do is this. Just set your MainActivity as the onTouchListener of the imageview, YOU.

```
public class MainActivity implements OnTouchListener { 
...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        touchx = (float) 200.0;//event.getX(); ive tried to just put solid numbers
        touchy = (float) 200.0;//event.getY(); but even that doesnt seem to work

        return true;
    }
...
}
```

In OnCreate(),

```
@Override
public void OnCreate(){
    ...
    // get ImageView instance like this. 
    ImageView YOU = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewId);
    ...
    // And set it. 
    YOU.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Actually, i haven't  implemented 'onTouchListener' interface in the MainActivity. But Can you show me how? I'm starting to think that the 'ontouchevent' could be not running at all.

Comment: Thanks, It works great, however I after I run the MoveCircleOnclick method again, it doesn't respond. Is there a way to fix this?(The only way to test the new code is to restart the app)

Comment: tried it again with movecircle as the touchlistener, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are trying to respond to a touch event in an ImageView (yes I am siggesting that as a possible route).  In that case in your onCreate or onCreateView method you want to add an OnTouchListener to the ImageView:

myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

```
touchx = event.getX();

touchy = event.getY();

return true; /* to consume the event */
```

}

}

That should do it for you.

Comment: This might sound stupid but how would I add a OnTouchListener to the ImageView on my onCreate method?

Comment: copy the code I listed above, substituting the name of your ImageView for "myImageView".  Before you do that you may want to create a Bitmap and a Canvas and attach those to the ImageView, but that is kind of another question...